# execute same function multiple times in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

i have one search function from external web service.
the search takes about 3 secs for searching data of one day to return number of records.
it is requested to search the data for one month continually.

so it is not sensible to do normal search (takes about 90 secs).

i would like to do search function with start and end date as parameters and returns the number of records.
and call this function in for loop (change the date range) and sum the records after finishing.

i think the best way is to do tasking or threading. but i couldn't accomplish this successfully.

so it will take 3 secs instead of 90 secs.

any help in that will much much appropriated.

Comment: I'd suggest posting some sample code here so people can see what you are trying to do in code, and then get back to you.

Comment: Do you have control of code of the external webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm reading your question correctly, this should start you off:

```
Module modSum

Private mSum As Integer
Public Property Sum() As Integer
    Get
        Return mSum
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        mSum = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub DoSum()

    For i = 1 To 30

        Dim dateToQuery As Date
        dateToQuery = Date.Parse("2013-02-" & i.ToString)


        Dim sc As New WebserviceCall
        sc.startdate = "2013-01-01"
        sc.enddate = "2013-01-31"

        Dim th As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf sc.DoServiceCall)
        th.Start()

    Next

End Sub

Public Class WebserviceCall

    Public startdate As Date
    Public enddate As Date

    Public Sub DoServiceCall()

        Dim ws As New YourService.Service
        Dim result As Integer = ws.GetSum(startdate, enddate)

        mSum += result

    End Sub

End Class

End Module
```

Comment: how i can pass multiple parameter to the function through th.Start(start_date,end_date)